# Accessing IHttpContextAccessor in action filter - is it dangerous?

Tags: asp.net-core

David Fowler and Damian Edwards recently gave a talk @ NDC London, about debugging asp.net core 2.0.

[In that talk](https://vimeo.com/254635669), they warn about controller action methods that do something async, and then try to access the `IHttpContextAccessor`, basically it's not thread safe.

I'm wondering if that only applies to action methods, and if it's safe to do this in an async action filter (I have something like this that runs on every request):

```
public class SampleAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public LoggedInUserAttribute(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Do something IO-bound more useful than...
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // Then set something on the IHttpContextAccessor...
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["Something"] = "Hello";

        await next();
    }

}
```

Comment: While I understand what it is you are trying to get answered. I see no need for using the accessor  in the filter as `ActionExecutingContext` already has a `HttpContext` property inherited from [ActionContext.HttpContext Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_HttpContext) which which makes the accessor redundant..

Comment: Ok after watching the talk at 2x I can tell you the the primary reason I gathered about the warning is because there is no `SynchronizationContext` in asp.net-core. So the same problem of thread safety can occur when trying to access the HttpContext via the accessor in async functions. And also the accessor hides errors and make it difficult to debug issues.

Comment: @Nkosi yeah that makes sense.. it's what I thought too, but wanted clarification on since the consequences could be quite nasty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is about accessing the HttpContext from multiple threads **in parallel**. The example in the talk describes that because of the IHttpContextAccessor, it's sometimes hard to tell what is accessing the HttpContext. The code you have above works fine, one thread is accessing the HttpContext at a time (though you don't ever need it in a filter because MVC gives it to you via the appropriate filter context).